# Hide Core Data store location on disk for external tools

Tags: ios, core-data

Currently my store resides in the Documents folder, and can be read by tools like IExplorer. So, I need to encrypt the sensitive contents, but I also want to prevent tools like that to be able to reach the store.

Is there a location where I can put the core data store on the iOS filesystem where tools like IExplorer can't reach it?

Comment: No, you can't, tools like IExplore can read the whole phone memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it !!

I turned on Data Protection in the iOS App ID Settings on Apple's Developer Portal.
After that, I had to regenerate my distribution profile and use that in the signing.

[image]

Now external tools like IExplorer cannot see anything anymore.